# Determination of carbon content of steel by liquid chemistry

Tags: analytical-chemistry, metallurgy

It seems like the typical laboratory methods for determining the carbon content of steel are to cuppellate it in a stream of oxygen and then measure the volume of the evolved $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{CO2}$, which involves many high-temperature complexities.

Why can't the carbon content of steel be measured by dissolving it in acid and reacting out the carbon at low temperature?

Comment: I am interested to know what happens the the carbon when steel when it is reacted with acid.  Would the reaction be different in nitric acid vs hydrochloric?

Comment: I don't know much about metallurgy. I think reaction of steel with acid leads to corrosion.  So does corrosion play any role here?

Answer (score 1):

I think cuppellate is a foreign word meaning "burn" essentially.

The basic technique would be to have the iron sample in a small ceramic boat which is put into a hot stream of $\ce{O2}$ so the iron and carbon both oxidize. The iron oxide stays in the boat, and the $\ce{CO2}$ is sweep away and trapped/reacted somehow. We talking small samples 10 grams perhaps.

If you try to dissolve the steel in an acid solution then the $\ce{CO2}$ gas is formed in solution. It is really hard to get a small amount of $\ce{CO2}$ out of solution given that you are starting with a small amount to begin with. Also if you try to scale up such a reaction it gets to be a problem. A $2~\mathrm{cm^3}$ block of iron takes a long time to dissolve in acid.

So choosing the analytical method depends on a lot of factors. Time per sample, sensitivity, and overall cost being the main ones.

Comment: May I introduce you to the `\ce{...}` notation? Use that in MathJax to get upright chemical expressions. E.g. `$\ce{C + O2 -> CO2}$` gives $\ce{C + O2 -> CO2}$. Learn more [on meta](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/444/7475)